# Converter documento word(DOC) para pdf usando python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, microsoft-word

Eu gostaria de converter um documento word(doc) para pdf usando o **python 2.7**.

Eu tenho este script, mas não entendi nada dele.

```
import sys
import os
import comtypes.client

wdFormatPDF = 17

in_file = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
out_file = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[2])

word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue o mesmo código comentado para um melhor entendimento:

**doc2pdf.py:**

```
import sys
import os
import comtypes.client

# Codigo correspondente ao formato .pdf
wdFormatPDF = 17

# Recupera o path completo (absoluto) do arquivo de
# entrada (.doc) a partir do primeiro parametro da
# linha de comando
in_file = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])

# Recupera o path completo (absoluto) do arquivo de
# saida (.pdf) a partir do segundo parametro da linha
# de comando
out_file = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[2])

# Cria instancia de um objeto COM para manipular Documentos Word
word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')

# Carrega Arquivo de entrada (.doc)
doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)

# Salva arquivo de saida em formato .pdf
doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)

# Fecha arquivo de Entrada
doc.Close()

# Finaliza instancia do Objeto COM criado
word.Quit()
```

Testando:

```
$ python doc2pdf.py entrada.doc saida.pdf
```